# LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING

Tags: windows, linux, user-interface, menu, wxpython

I created recently a piece of code that always showed me a message like this twice when I closed it:

> (python:11712): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

What I want is to get rid from that warning.
This piece of code reproduce such behaviour (the message appears once when closed):

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title="Sample")
    menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
    filemenu = wx.Menu()
    filemenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY,"&Pass")
    menuBar.Append(filemenu,"&File")
    self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frame = MyFrame(None)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

It works perfectly, yet the warning message appears when I close the app.
That's a Linux-only message, nothing appears when I tried it on Windows.

A work around I used was to bind a close event handler in my frame

```
  def __init__(self, parent):
    ... # Previous code here
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)
```

And make such event handler as

```
  def OnClose(self, evt):
    for menu in self.GetMenuBar().GetMenus(): # (wx.Menu, caption) tuples
      menu[0].Destroy() # Bad parents won't remove you, you'll DIE before!!!
    evt.Skip()
```

That worked ok in that simple app on Linux, however it crashed when I tried on Windows. So I wanted to see what was happening in the runtime while on Linux, replacing the line

```
      menu[0].Destroy()
```

to

```
      print menu[0].Parent
```

And it showed me "None" as answer. However I couldn't make that:

```
      menu[0].Parent = self
```

And neither:

```
      menu[0].Parent = self.GetMenuBar()
```

Since both raises TypeError:

> TypeError: in method 'Menu_SetParent', expected argument 2 of type 'wxMenu *'

Answer (score 0):

This is a GTK warning. You could debug it (with `gdb` and a debugging variant of your Gtk and Glib libraries - e.g. `libgtk-3-0-dbg`  and `libglib2.0-0-dbg` packages on Ubuntu or Debian) by [running](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-running.html) with the environment variable

```
 export G_DEBUG=fatal-warnings
```

I have no idea if the bug is in Gtk itself, in WxWidget, in the C glues for Python, or in your Python code.